# javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: socket closed

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I try to authorize user via LDAP.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = getUserNameFromAuth(auth);
        String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();
        HelpDescUser userDetails = (HelpDescUser) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        String email = userDetails.getEmail();
        String url = "ldap://" + ldapHost + ":" + port + "/";
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ldapProvider =
                    new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(null, url, rootDn);
        ldapProvider.setSearchFilter(filter);
        Authentication authenticate = ldapProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        }
}
```

I receive this:

> Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: okmarket.ru:636;
>   socket closed     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:426)
>     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:365)
>     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
>     at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2795)
>     at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:320)   at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
>     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
>     at
>   java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
>     at
>   java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
>     at
>   java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
>     at
>   java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
>     at
>   java.naming/javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.(InitialLdapContext.java:154)

What wrong? Is problem in my side, or on LDAP side?

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue or incorrect connection parameters, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601979/tomcat-ldap-issue-socket-closed-on-connection

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, I just tried to connect with `ldap://` and port `636`.
Correct way is to make `ldaps://` request or to set port `389`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server details.Are you able to ping to the server.

Comment: Please put this in comment section of the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the LDAP is up or not. Seems like LDAP is Down.